# Сортировка при парсинге JSON

Tags: python, json, сортировка

```
import json
a = []
people = '[{"name": "Haley Whitney", "country": "British Indian Ocean Territory (Chagos Archipelago)", "age": 54}, {"name": "Matthew King", "country": "Colombia", "age": 34}, {"name": "Sean Sullivan", "country": "Mayotte", "age": 40}, {"name": "Christian Crawford", "country": "Russian Federation", "age": 29}, {"name": "Sarah Contreras", "country": "Honduras", "age": 82}, {"name": "Danielle Williams", "country": "Togo", "age": 91}, {"name": "Jonathan Wilson", "country": "Tunisia", "age": 49}, {"name": "Patricia Wilkerson", "country": "Georgia", "age": 22}, {"name": "Zachary Scott", "country": "Brunei Darussalam", "age": 55}, {"name": "Elizabeth Sanchez", "country": "Nauru", "age": 23}, {"name": "Christina Fernandez", "country": "Burundi", "age": 71}, {"name": "Allen Norton", "country": "Montserrat", "age": 79}, {"name": "Scott Arroyo", "country": "Montenegro", "age": 72}, {"name": "Brooke Boyd", "country": "Latvia", "age": 74}, {"name": "Jerry Morrow", "country": "San Marino", "age": 23}, {"name": "Danielle Bradshaw", "country": "Vietnam", "age": 64}, {"name": "Jerry Thompson", "country": "Belgium", "age": 30}, {"name": "Mark Jordan", "country": "Comoros", "age": 89}, {"name": "Joseph Berger", "country": "Cook Islands", "age": 94}, {"name": "Gina Brooks", "country": "Samoa", "age": 51}, {"name": "Walter Duran", "country": "Chad", "age": 67}, {"name": "John Martinez", "country": "Wallis and Futuna", "age": 65}, {"name": "Johnny Glover", "country": "Eritrea", "age": 72}, {"name": "Lindsay Moore", "country": "Liberia", "age": 53}, {"name": "Kimberly Burton", "country": "Nicaragua", "age": 92}, {"name": "Jacqueline Ballard", "country": "Nigeria", "age": 78}, {"name": "Charles Thompson", "country": "Saudi Arabia", "age": 50}, {"name": "Suzanne Roberts", "country": "Serbia", "age": 43}, {"name": "David Decker", "country": "South Africa", "age": 71}, {"name": "Christopher Perez", "country": "Cayman Islands", "age": 49}, {"name": "Debra Hall", "country": "Greece", "age": 13}, {"name": "John King", "country": "Bahamas", "age": 40}, {"name": "Justin Galvan", "country": "Namibia", "age": 19}, {"name": "Jacqueline Berger", "country": "Yemen", "age": 59}, {"name": "Shawn Robinson", "country": "Saint Pierre and Miquelon", "age": 32}, {"name": "Kristen Garcia", "country": "Portugal", "age": 48}, {"name": "Christopher Barry", "country": "French Polynesia", "age": 23}, {"name": "Alejandra Cook", "country": "Egypt", "age": 16}, {"name": "Jill Harrell", "country": "Comoros", "age": 49}, {"name": "Sara Zimmerman", "country": "Brazil", "age": 26}, {"name": "Mrs. Charlene Flores", "country": "New Caledonia", "age": 75}, {"name": "Melissa Crawford", "country": "Lebanon", "age": 17}, {"name": "Larry Wong", "country": "New Caledonia", "age": 6}, {"name": "Brenda Acosta", "country": "Grenada", "age": 48}, {"name": "Latoya Terry", "country": "Saint Martin", "age": 41}, {"name": "Seth Luna", "country": "Sao Tome and Principe", "age": 59}, {"name": "Micheal Adams", "country": "Barbados", "age": 53}, {"name": "Susan Carroll", "country": "Somalia", "age": 64}, {"name": "Douglas Morris", "country": "Thailand", "age": 24}, {"name": "Dennis Wagner", "country": "Zimbabwe", "age": 66}, {"name": "Kristin Johnson", "country": "Niue", "age": 71}, {"name": "Steven Krause", "country": "Turkmenistan", "age": 84}, {"name": "Jared Smith", "country": "Colombia", "age": 46}, {"name": "Lauren Anderson", "country": "Christmas Island", "age": 46}, {"name": "Joshua Spencer", "country": "Russian Federation", "age": 38}, {"name": "Maria Edwards", "country": "Hungary", "age": 78}, {"name": "Anne Lee", "country": "United States of America", "age": 10}, {"name": "James Mckenzie", "country": "Uganda", "age": 43}, {"name": "Joshua Gallegos", "country": "United States Minor Outlying Islands", "age": 27}, {"name": "Paul Herrera", "country": "Kiribati", "age": 17}, {"name": "Veronica White", "country": "Gabon", "age": 88}, {"name": "Michael Hall", "country": "China", "age": 43}, {"name": "Sabrina Thompson", "country": "Chad", "age": 27}, {"name": "Jennifer Archer", "country": "Korea", "age": 45}, {"name": "Christina Simmons", "country": "Israel", "age": 80}, {"name": "Travis White", "country": "Central African Republic", "age": 31}, {"name": "Dennis Hernandez", "country": "Slovenia", "age": 66}, {"name": "Matthew Richards", "country": "Svalbard & Jan Mayen Islands", "age": 34}, {"name": "Stephen Curry", "country": "Finland", "age": 92}, {"name": "Margaret Williamson", "country": "Hong Kong", "age": 86}, {"name": "Mary Estes", "country": "Montenegro", "age": 19}, {"name": "Alex Scott", "country": "Christmas Island", "age": 67}, {"name": "John Andrews", "country": "Bahamas", "age": 68}, {"name": "Jonathan Willis", "country": "Saint Martin", "age": 23}, {"name": "Olivia Campos", "country": "Armenia", "age": 72}, {"name": "Diana Davis", "country": "Azerbaijan", "age": 54}, {"name": "Jack Cummings", "country": "Martinique", "age": 94}, {"name": "Kaitlyn Mcdonald", "country": "Austria", "age": 12}, {"name": "Maria Blake", "country": "Pitcairn Islands", "age": 91}, {"name": "Kelly Thomas", "country": "Ethiopia", "age": 74}, {"name": "John Terrell Jr.", "country": "India", "age": 50}, {"name": "Lindsay Wood", "country": "United Arab Emirates", "age": 72}, {"name": "Matthew Gilbert", "country": "Madagascar", "age": 86}, {"name": "Tanner Johnson", "country": "Congo", "age": 11}, {"name": "Michael Garcia", "country": "Liberia", "age": 45}, {"name": "Nicole Johnson", "country": "Barbados", "age": 54}, {"name": "William Lee", "country": "Lithuania", "age": 59}, {"name": "Jeffrey Coffey", "country": "Faroe Islands", "age": 88}, {"name": "Sandra Freeman", "country": "Philippines", "age": 35}, {"name": "Latoya Maxwell", "country": "Sweden", "age": 12}, {"name": "Darius Blevins", "country": "Thailand", "age": 29}, {"name": "Teresa Newman", "country": "Jersey", "age": 6}, {"name": "Larry Bray", "country": "Brunei Darussalam", "age": 21}, {"name": "Adam Roberson", "country": "Jordan", "age": 71}, {"name": "Michael Gomez", "country": "Tajikistan", "age": 37}, {"name": "Abigail Mccarthy", "country": "Kiribati", "age": 85}, {"name": "Tom Morris", "country": "Cayman Islands", "age": 27}, {"name": "Kevin Wagner", "country": "Suriname", "age": 55}, {"name": "Peggy Bryant", "country": "Korea", "age": 36}, {"name": "Erik Mclaughlin", "country": "Austria", "age": 24}]'

data = json.loads(people)

for i in sorted(data, key=lambda x: x['age'], x['name']): #Мой ключ
    print(i)
```

Как мне выводить(print) вложенные списки в порядке возрастания возраста, а если возраст равен то в алфавитном порядке(их имен)

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте код, которым вы пытались решить задачу и опишите что с ним не так.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy я не смог написать ключ для сортировки, так что кода считайте и нет

Comment: Добавьте код с каким-нибудь ключом. Нужно ваше решение, которое вам помогут довести до ума.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Добавил

Comment: Опечатка: `lambda x: (x['age'], x['name'])`. Вы пытались вызвать `sorted` с тремя аргументами. Это из-за запятых.

Answer (score 0):

```py
# Если у вас данные действительно в виде строки то нужно ее в словарь преобразовать

import json

js = '[{"name": "Haley Whitney", "country": "British Indian Ocean Territory (Chagos Archipelago)", "age": 54}, {"name": "Matthew King", "country": "Colombia", "age": 34}, {"name": "Sean Sullivan", "country": "Mayotte", "age": 40}, {"name": "Christian Crawford", "country": "Russian Federation", "age": 29}, {"name": "Sarah Contreras", "country": "Honduras", "age": 82}, {"name": "Danielle Williams", "country": "Togo", "age": 91}, {"name": "Jonathan Wilson", "country": "Tunisia", "age": 49}, {"name": "Patricia Wilkerson", "country": "Georgia", "age": 22}, {"name": "Zachary Scott", "country": "Brunei Darussalam", "age": 55}, {"name": "Elizabeth Sanchez", "country": "Nauru", "age": 23}, {"name": "Christina Fernandez", "country": "Burundi", "age": 71}, {"name": "Allen Norton", "country": "Montserrat", "age": 79}, {"name": "Scott Arroyo", "country": "Montenegro", "age": 72}, {"name": "Brooke Boyd", "country": "Latvia", "age": 74}, {"name": "Jerry Morrow", "country": "San Marino", "age": 23}, {"name": "Danielle Bradshaw", "country": "Vietnam", "age": 64}, {"name": "Jerry Thompson", "country": "Belgium", "age": 30}, {"name": "Mark Jordan", "country": "Comoros", "age": 89}, {"name": "Joseph Berger", "country": "Cook Islands", "age": 94}, {"name": "Gina Brooks", "country": "Samoa", "age": 51}, {"name": "Walter Duran", "country": "Chad", "age": 67}, {"name": "John Martinez", "country": "Wallis and Futuna", "age": 65}, {"name": "Johnny Glover", "country": "Eritrea", "age": 72}, {"name": "Lindsay Moore", "country": "Liberia", "age": 53}, {"name": "Kimberly Burton", "country": "Nicaragua", "age": 92}, {"name": "Jacqueline Ballard", "country": "Nigeria", "age": 78}, {"name": "Charles Thompson", "country": "Saudi Arabia", "age": 50}, {"name": "Suzanne Roberts", "country": "Serbia", "age": 43}, {"name": "David Decker", "country": "South Africa", "age": 71}, {"name": "Christopher Perez", "country": "Cayman Islands", "age": 49}, {"name": "Debra Hall", "country": "Greece", "age": 13}, {"name": "John King", "country": "Bahamas", "age": 40}, {"name": "Justin Galvan", "country": "Namibia", "age": 19}, {"name": "Jacqueline Berger", "country": "Yemen", "age": 59}, {"name": "Shawn Robinson", "country": "Saint Pierre and Miquelon", "age": 32}, {"name": "Kristen Garcia", "country": "Portugal", "age": 48}, {"name": "Christopher Barry", "country": "French Polynesia", "age": 23}, {"name": "Alejandra Cook", "country": "Egypt", "age": 16}, {"name": "Jill Harrell", "country": "Comoros", "age": 49}, {"name": "Sara Zimmerman", "country": "Brazil", "age": 26}, {"name": "Mrs. Charlene Flores", "country": "New Caledonia", "age": 75}, {"name": "Melissa Crawford", "country": "Lebanon", "age": 17}, {"name": "Larry Wong", "country": "New Caledonia", "age": 6}, {"name": "Brenda Acosta", "country": "Grenada", "age": 48}, {"name": "Latoya Terry", "country": "Saint Martin", "age": 41}, {"name": "Seth Luna", "country": "Sao Tome and Principe", "age": 59}, {"name": "Micheal Adams", "country": "Barbados", "age": 53}, {"name": "Susan Carroll", "country": "Somalia", "age": 64}, {"name": "Douglas Morris", "country": "Thailand", "age": 24}, {"name": "Dennis Wagner", "country": "Zimbabwe", "age": 66}, {"name": "Kristin Johnson", "country": "Niue", "age": 71}, {"name": "Steven Krause", "country": "Turkmenistan", "age": 84}, {"name": "Jared Smith", "country": "Colombia", "age": 46}, {"name": "Lauren Anderson", "country": "Christmas Island", "age": 46}, {"name": "Joshua Spencer", "country": "Russian Federation", "age": 38}, {"name": "Maria Edwards", "country": "Hungary", "age": 78}, {"name": "Anne Lee", "country": "United States of America", "age": 10}, {"name": "James Mckenzie", "country": "Uganda", "age": 43}, {"name": "Joshua Gallegos", "country": "United States Minor Outlying Islands", "age": 27}, {"name": "Paul Herrera", "country": "Kiribati", "age": 17}, {"name": "Veronica White", "country": "Gabon", "age": 88}, {"name": "Michael Hall", "country": "China", "age": 43}, {"name": "Sabrina Thompson", "country": "Chad", "age": 27}, {"name": "Jennifer Archer", "country": "Korea", "age": 45}, {"name": "Christina Simmons", "country": "Israel", "age": 80}, {"name": "Travis White", "country": "Central African Republic", "age": 31}, {"name": "Dennis Hernandez", "country": "Slovenia", "age": 66}, {"name": "Matthew Richards", "country": "Svalbard & Jan Mayen Islands", "age": 34}, {"name": "Stephen Curry", "country": "Finland", "age": 92}, {"name": "Margaret Williamson", "country": "Hong Kong", "age": 86}, {"name": "Mary Estes", "country": "Montenegro", "age": 19}, {"name": "Alex Scott", "country": "Christmas Island", "age": 67}, {"name": "John Andrews", "country": "Bahamas", "age": 68}, {"name": "Jonathan Willis", "country": "Saint Martin", "age": 23}, {"name": "Olivia Campos", "country": "Armenia", "age": 72}, {"name": "Diana Davis", "country": "Azerbaijan", "age": 54}, {"name": "Jack Cummings", "country": "Martinique", "age": 94}, {"name": "Kaitlyn Mcdonald", "country": "Austria", "age": 12}, {"name": "Maria Blake", "country": "Pitcairn Islands", "age": 91}, {"name": "Kelly Thomas", "country": "Ethiopia", "age": 74}, {"name": "John Terrell Jr.", "country": "India", "age": 50}, {"name": "Lindsay Wood", "country": "United Arab Emirates", "age": 72}, {"name": "Matthew Gilbert", "country": "Madagascar", "age": 86}, {"name": "Tanner Johnson", "country": "Congo", "age": 11}, {"name": "Michael Garcia", "country": "Liberia", "age": 45}, {"name": "Nicole Johnson", "country": "Barbados", "age": 54}, {"name": "William Lee", "country": "Lithuania", "age": 59}, {"name": "Jeffrey Coffey", "country": "Faroe Islands", "age": 88}, {"name": "Sandra Freeman", "country": "Philippines", "age": 35}, {"name": "Latoya Maxwell", "country": "Sweden", "age": 12}, {"name": "Darius Blevins", "country": "Thailand", "age": 29}, {"name": "Teresa Newman", "country": "Jersey", "age": 6}, {"name": "Larry Bray", "country": "Brunei Darussalam", "age": 21}, {"name": "Adam Roberson", "country": "Jordan", "age": 71}, {"name": "Michael Gomez", "country": "Tajikistan", "age": 37}, {"name": "Abigail Mccarthy", "country": "Kiribati", "age": 85}, {"name": "Tom Morris", "country": "Cayman Islands", "age": 27}, {"name": "Kevin Wagner", "country": "Suriname", "age": 55}, {"name": "Peggy Bryant", "country": "Korea", "age": 36}, {"name": "Erik Mclaughlin", "country": "Austria", "age": 24}]'

data = json.loads(js)

def simple_key(item: dict):
    return item.get('age'), item.get('name')

data.sort(key=simple_key)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]